# Entering Schengen state on single entry visa

Tags: schengen

I am from Pakistan and I have a single-entry Schengen visa issued by the Italian Embassy. My purpose of visit is tourism and I have purchased Euro train tickets to travel in the Schengen states for about 41 days, staying at different places.

Can I enter the Schengen area first in Berlin, Germany? My girlfriend's visa was issued visa by German Embassy and we want to travel together.

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended to enter first in the country you applied for.

As it is stated in [point 16](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf) (which is connected to point six): "It is therefore recommended that you carry with you copies of the documents which you presented when applying for the visa (e.g. letters of invitation, travel confirmations, other documents stating the purpose of your stay)" It is recommended to follow the path that has been presented in the application.

If you go first to Italy you may get lots of questions from Officer. I've experienced that. However, if you answer them accurately, there should be a no problem.

Comment: Recommended by whom? Do you have any official source to support that assertion?

Comment: https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf

Comment: Point six says "as a general rule you may cross any Schengen border with a visa issued by any Schengen country."  This undermines your point rather than supporting it. It goes on to note that a Schengen visa holder can be denied entry at the border; this is true regardless of which country issued the visa.

Comment: It is a good idea to follow the itinerary that was presented during the application. If that itinerary said one would visit some country first, one should do so.

Comment: @phoog As it is stated in point 16 (which is connected to point six): "It is therefore recommended that you carry with you copies of the documents which you presented when applying for the visa (e.g. letters of invitation, travel confirmations, other documents stating the purpose of your stay)" It is recommended to follow the path that has been presented in the application. There is nothing complicated. I have had the similar experience. So I can tell you that sometimes it's up to officer on the border how he will look at the subject.

Comment: Sure, but "follow the path that had been presented in the application" is hardly the same as "enter the country that issued the visa" -- and I only just noticed that you wrote "applied for," which I had been reading as "applied to." If you edit your question to incorporate the information in your last comment I'll reverse my down vote and encourage others to do the same.

Comment: @phoog let me know if there is something I should edit. Thank you.